# Writing Image to Clipboard on iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, copy, clipboard

My code to write an image to the clipboard is not working on iPad IOS Safari or Chrome. Working fine on Chrome and Safari on MacOS, Windows and iPhone IOS. No error being thrown. I'm stumped!

```
    document.getElementById("shareButton").addEventListener('click', async function() { 
        share.show();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("shareImage");
        var makeImagePromise = async () => {
            let blob = await new Promise(resolve => canvas.toBlob(resolve));
            return await blob;
            }
            
        navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ "image/png": makeImagePromise() })])
        });
```